# Multiple classToggle elements

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a div where when you click on an element and the div slides up, it reveals another div behind it. I would then like to have an element within the 'back' div that when clicked it will slide the 'front' div back down.

Here is my attempt/s! - http://jsfiddle.net/danieljoseph/t2n3p/36/

I currently can slide the front div up but cannot use another element to slide it back down. i am using css3 for the animation but if it would be better another way please let me know.

Here is the JQuery code i'm using:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
$('#top-layer').addClass('top-collapse');
$(this).removeClass('top-collapse');
});
```

Please let me know if you need me to explain this better!

Thanks

Comment: You forgot HTML DOM Elements in your JSFiddle.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't update/save what i had done... possibly because i was way to high to be coding! Should be done now.

Comment: Can anyone help with this?